# Function that has sequences approaches $\infty$ and $-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Assume $f$ be a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ and  there exist sequences $a_n$ goes to $\infty$ and sequence $b_n$ goes to  $-\infty$ such that  $f(a_n)$ goes  $0$  and $f(b_n)$  goes $0.$ What we can tell about $f$? why this property is important ?  Thank you in advance

**Edit** The OP has been edited.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis, How if $f$ has a dense graph does that tell any thing. Or this can not happen with this properties

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis That is not really true. Pick $a_n = 2\pi n$ and $b_n=-2\pi n$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$. That function is continuous, but the limit does not exist.

Comment: ??? If $f(x)=1/x$ then $f(a_n)=0$ is impossible.

Comment: To sort of answer your question, no, nothing interesting really follows, unless you have more information about $f$.

Comment: I have very little hope that you get any property for free. You only know a bunch of values of your function. You can infer some trivial things like $\liminf_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) \leq 0$ and $\limsup_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, $f(a_n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $n\neq 0$

Comment: Yes, but $\frac{1}{n}\neq 0...$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, Oh. you are right. I kept that I will take the limit

Comment: I think you should ask yourself what kind of property you hope to get from this super weak conditions. You will not get any regularity or integrability (not even measurability). From my point of view, you will exactly your assumptions.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, your are right. I fixed now

Comment: Severin Schraven,  I need to ensure something about continuity in some interval in half of the interval the the function is constant $0$ and the other function has the property in OP. My aim, I need to ensure the is continuous at $x$ when it is restriction to this interval .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dear function $f$ is just defined pointwise and no any other conditions, then your given criteria tells almost nothing since for any $x\neq a_n,b_n$ you can define $f(x)$ however you want. If $f$ is continuous, still this tells almost nothing useful. Even for stronger conditions such as $f\in C^n(\mathbb{R})$, still I cannot come up with any useful result.

If $f$ has some strong property, such as monotonicity, then instantly you will conclude $f\equiv 0$. Also if $f$ was convex or concave, you gain that $f\equiv 0$.

Now if $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $\|f'\|_{L^\infty}\leq c$, then you can get a control of $f$ by $|f(x)|\leq\frac{c|c_n-c_{n'}|}{2}$ where $x\in[c_n,c_{n'}]$ ($c_n=a_n$ when $n\geq 0$ and $c_n=-b_n$ if not). Similar result can be extended to $n$th derivative.

For now this is all I can think of. If you are struggling with some certain problem, then it will be helpful to hear the problem itself since the condition you mentioned seems very weak.

Comment: Jingeon &Severin Schraven . I add more information to the question now